# Apache wont start after attempting to install SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

Below is what my VirtualHosts look like in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin support@mydomain.com
  ServerName  mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/public

  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/mydomain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mydomain.com.key

  ServerName  mydomain.com
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain.com/public

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using the latest version of Apache on CentOS and there isn't any error being generated.  Apache just will not start. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE - Found these messages in the error log:

```
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] Init: Private key not found
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218710120 error:0D094068:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad tag
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] SSL Library Error: 218734605 error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib
```

Comment: If you add the Log configuration to the VirtualHost *:443, do you get any more info ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It can not find `/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mydomain.com.key` file.

In the logs you have:

```
[Tue Mar 16 02:07:57 2010] [error] Init: Private key not found
```

The related configuration is:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mydomain.com.key
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the mod_ssl package

Comment: It's already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` exist?  If they do, it looks like they're malformed.