# CentOS6 - Apache2 working but when installing / enabling SSL, server won't start because of permissions error

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl, centos6, mod-ssl

I'm attempting to install Apache with SSL on **CentOS6** to use as a development server.

I've been following the directions posted here to get SSL working: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Https (Note: Apache was working fine until I attempted to enable SSL.)

When I got to part about re-starting Apache, the server wouldn't start. I just get an error which follows:

```
[Mon Feb 13 18:31:36 2012] [error] (13)Permission denied: Init: Can't open 
 server certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
```

I saw that the reported certificate was owned by my user and my group, so I changed it to `root:root` but it made no difference. I'm not sure what else to try or what to look at. Thanks.

*Note: My questions is similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/122805/apache-wont-start-after-attempting-to-install-ssl) but the error is different.*

Comment: What is the result of running getenforce? Did you use copy like the docs say when creating the certificate?

Comment: "getenforce" returns "Enforcing"

Comment: Yes, I double checked that it was a copy.

Comment: Christopher -- apparently that was it, in a way. I want to give you credit for the answer. Could you write something along the lines of using the restorecon piece? When you posted that, I recalled that there were directions to run `restorecon -RvF /etc/pki`. I ran this as a precaution and now the server starts.

Answer (score 11):

So for anyone who doesn't understand what the answer actually is here:

This is an selinux issue. Files can have different selinux "contexts" and a file with the wrong context will be unreadable by the httpd daemon even if the regular permissions are correct. In my case, the solution was to do the following:

```
chcon --reference /file/with/correct/context /path/to/certificate/file
```

Which will copy the context from the referenced file to the certificate.  In case you don't have a file you can reference, the slightly trickier way (because of having to type it out) to set the correct context is:

```
chcon unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 /path/to/certificate/file
```

Comment: One might encounter this issue when uploading the key file as a regular user, then using `sudo mv` (with requisite `sudo chown`) to install.  Safest route is to `cat > /path/to/file.crt < /path/to/source.crt`.